# Constraints options don't appear in some .xib files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Does anyone know why in some .xib files in my Xcode project the icons to add constraints don't show up??

With add constraints icons:

[image]

Without add constraints icons:

[image]

Comment: Check if the auto layout is enabled for this xib file or not.

Comment: OMG Thanks!!! this was the problem

Answer (score -1):

Can you try clicking on one off the inner views like button or label.

Comment: This is not an answer... it should be a comment.